# iOS / Obj-C - Cells in tableView displaying same data multiple times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

For some reason, my tableView is displaying the data of my most recently posted item multiple times, even though there are 10 different items to display in my array. **E.g.** instead of displaying the 10 different items in my tableView cells, it simply displays the most recent post 10 times in all 10 cells? Any idea why this might be? I tried using two different cell identifiers to see if that would fix the problem, but no dice. See code below.

**ViewController.m**

```
- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableview

{
    return 1;

}


- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


       if (neighbourDetail > 0 ) {


           NSString *thisUserId = [neighbourDetail objectForKey:@"uid"];


           NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                                     thisUserId];

          NSArray *resultArray = [self.reviewData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];


           return [resultArray count];

} else {


    NSString *thisUserId = [self.myFriendData objectForKey:@"uid2"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                              thisUserId];

   NSArray *resultArray = [self.reviewData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    return [resultArray count];


}

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    if (neighbourDetail > 0 ) {

        static NSString *DogTableIdentifier = @"ReviewTableViewCell";

        ReviewTableViewCell *cell = (ReviewTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DogTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReviewTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }
        NSString *thisUserId = [neighbourDetail objectForKey:@"uid"];


        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                                  thisUserId];

        NSArray *resultArray = [self.reviewData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];



        NSString *reviewDes = resultArray[0][@"body"];
        cell.reviewText.text = reviewDes;


        NSString *firstName = resultArray[0][@"from first"];
        cell.firstText.text = firstName;


        NSString *timeStamp = resultArray[0][@"published at"];
        cell.timeText.text = timeStamp;

        NSString *secondLink = resultArray[0][@"from photo"];


        [cell.profilePic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]];

        return cell;


    } else if (neighbourDetail == NULL)  {

        static NSString *DogTableIdentifier2 = @"ReviewTableViewCell";

        ReviewTableViewCell *cellTwo = (ReviewTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DogTableIdentifier2];
        if (cellTwo == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReviewTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cellTwo = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }

        NSString *thisUserId = [self.myFriendData objectForKey:@"uid2"];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                                  thisUserId];

        NSArray *resultArray = [self.reviewData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];


        NSString *reviewDes = resultArray[0][@"body"];
        cellTwo.reviewText.text = reviewDes;

        NSString *firstName = resultArray[0][@"from first"];
        cellTwo.firstText.text = firstName;


        NSString *timeStamp = resultArray[0][@"published at"];
        cellTwo.timeText.text = timeStamp;

        NSString *secondLink = resultArray[0][@"from photo"];


        [cellTwo.profilePic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]];


        return cellTwo;
    }

    return 0;

    }
```

Comment: May be Dublicate value contain in your array.

Comment: resultArray[0] should be resultArray[indexPath.row]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are showing only first element of array in cell  like

```
NSString *reviewDes = resultArray[0][@"body"];
```

It should be

```
NSString *reviewDes = resultArray[indexPath.row][@"body"];
```

And it is better to keep `strong` reference  rather than filter every time in `cellForRow` and `numberOfRow`

like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *resultArray;
```

and assign it in when your data comes either from Webservice or Local database

it makes your cell a bit faster

Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: You're 100% right - thank you SO much haha. I'll accept this answer once it let's me (says I need to wait 5 min).

Comment: @Brittany Welcome .... try it and let me know if you have still issue . Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because every time you filtered the data with same user ID and as result this is showing always same result.

If result Array will always return 1 then its ok otherwise you have to use `resultArray[indexPath.row]` instead of `resultArray[0]`

What is `neighbourDetail` contains?

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRow method, you made a mistake:

```
resultArray[0] --> resultArray[indexPath.row]
```

You need to give your current indexPath's row to your cell, so it will display as per your row.

Checkout more about [indexPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexpath).

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRow method, you are populating data always from resultArray[0].

```
    resultArray[0] ----> resultArray[indexPath.row]
```

The expression indexPath.row increments by 1 for each row and is basically row number.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use this Simple code

```
 NSArray *resultArray = [self.reviewData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSDictionary*dict=[resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cellTwo.reviewText.text = [dict valueForKey:@"body"];
cellTwo.firstText.text = [dict valueForKey:@"from"];
cellTwo.timeText.text = [dict valueForKey:@"published at"];

NSString *secondLink = [dict valueForKey:@"from photo"];


[cellTwo.profilePic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]];


return cellTwo;
```

Answer (score 0):

IndexPath in UITableView delegate and datasource methods will help you identify precisely which section and which row you are working on. From apple documentation

> func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?
>
> Parameters **IndexPath** The index path locating the row in the tableview.

So when you are working on tableview you can use indexpath to access particular cell. While populating cell or while selection of tableView use indexPath not hard coded index.
In your case you have used `resultArray[0]` where you should have used `resultArray[indexPath.row]`.